# Move border-bottom further down?

Tags: html, css

Is there an easy way to just move the border down 5px? Like some trick would be great...

```css
   h2{
    display: inline-block;
    }
    .video{
    vertical-align: middle;
    }
    .item{
      border-bottom: 1px solid green;
    }
```

```html
      <div class="item">
    <iframe class="video" width="200" height="100" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
     <h2>title</h2>
    </div>
```

Comment: here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/n5tseg3k/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could just add some padding to the bottom of your `.item` container via the [`padding-bottom`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding-bottom) property :

```
.item{
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}
```

This can be seen below using the red line (as white was hard to see) :

[image]

**Example**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <style>
    h2 {
      display: inline-block;
    }
    .video {
      vertical-align: middle;
    }
    .item {
      padding-bottom: 5px;
      border-bottom: 1px solid red;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="item">
    <iframe class="video" width="200" height="100" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <h2>title</h2>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes with `padding-bottom` property.

```
.item{
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n5tseg3k/1/)

Comment: Thank you aswell just what i looked for!